# How to Search a Database Table using One of Two Fields from ASP:TextBox and asp:dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

I have one textbox to search based on staff name and dropdownlist to search based on staff type. if staff name is entered repeater should load based on txtbox text, if dropdown selected load data related to that perticular selected value. if both are present like if textbox value is entered and as well as dropdown is selected load repeater based on both the data.

Below is the code snippet of search option.

```
int stype = int.Parse(ddlStafType.SelectedValue);
        if (txtsearchname.Text == "" && ddlStafType.SelectedValue == "0")
        {
            idLoadData();
        }
        else
        {
            using (iSchoolDBEntities db = new iSchoolDBEntities())
            {
                var details = (from si in db.School_StaffInfo
                               join st in db.iSchool_StaffType on si.StaffTypeID equals st.StaffTypeID
                               where ((si.SchoolID == schlid) && (si.isDeleted != true)) && ((si.StaffName.StartsWith(txtsearchname.Text)) && (si.StaffTypeID == stype) && ((si.StaffTypeID == stype) || (si.StaffName.StartsWith(txtsearchname.Text))))
                               select new
                               {
                                   si.StaffID,
                                   si.StaffName,
                                   si.EmployeeCode,
                                   st.StaffType,
                                   si.UserName
                               });
                RptallStaff.DataSource = details.ToList();
                RptallStaff.DataBind();
            }
        }
```